# In SharePoint Modern, how can I create clickable images that change content on the same page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

My goal is to display a group of images on one part of a page and when any of the images are clicked, rich text content is displayed in a different part of the same page. See mock-up for what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB web part to meet your requirement.

As a workaround, there is a web part: **Hero**, which is similar to your situation.

We can display up to five items in the Hero web part and use compelling images, text, and links to draw attention to each:
[image]

And we can change the links, images, and text for each tile or layer using the Edit details button Edit details for each tile or layer.
[image]

We suggest you display the rich text in another page, then refer to the page link in "Call to action link":

[image]

Comment: So I understand correctly, this would take the user away from the page, correct? So in the example above if a user clicked on the Ocean image they would go to a new page that might have one or two sentences describing the image? That UX would be extremely poor and a deal breaker for my needs. Is there something like the old Content Editor webpart that could leverage some JS or something to do this?